# How to get specific key and its value from property file using java

Tags: java

I have n number of line in properties in the property file,

```
abc=test
efg=tes1
hij=test2
```

How can I get the 3rd value which is 'hij' and its value in Java.

I have tried like this but it only reads the first key 'abc'

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      int index = line.indexOf('=');
      if (index > 0) {
         String key = line.substring(0, index).trim();
         String value = line.substring(index + 1).trim();
         p.put(key, value);
         if(p.entrySet() != null) {  //trying to store key value
                String getkey = key;   
         }
```

Please let me know how to iterate and check whether a specific key is matched and then get the corresponding value.

Comment: What about using the Properties class and its `load` method. Then you can simply use getProperty.

Comment: @Norbert can you please provide sample code.. I am very new to this.

Comment: Straight from Wikipedia ;)

Properties properties = new Properties();
BufferedInputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("beispiel.properties"));
properties.load(stream);
stream.close();
String hijValue = properties.getProperty("hij");

Comment: @Norbert   I want to read it dynamically, not hard coded like properties.getProperty("hij") , is there any way to do it dynamically?

Comment: @Norbert  like i will have a variable String Sample = hij; and i want to check whether the property file contains this key if has then store the key and the value.

Comment: you can use a parameter to make it "dynamic" and if the key is not there the value is null so you can add a null check. Or work with an Optional and so on. Please check some code examples for the Properties class.

Comment: @Norbert any sample code please ,unable to find appropriate examples.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are many ways to do this. You can iterate the properties using `ResourceBundle`. The `ResourceBundle.getBundle("fileName")` accepts the property file name without the `.properties` extension.

Should you frequently need some key-values, you can iterate once and store all key-value pairs in a map and simply query from the map in your next search.

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
@Component
public class MyProperties{
    
    private static ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("application");

    public void execute() {
        
        Enumeration<String> all = resourceBundle.getKeys();
        String key,value;
        while(all.hasMoreElements()){
            key = all.nextElement();
            //you can check your key match here and break out
            
            value = resourceBundle.getString(key);
            //value = environment.getProperty(key);
            System.out.printf("key=%s, value=%s\n",key,value);
        }
    }
}
```